# How to list shared with me files not yet in MyDrive

Tags: c#, .net, google-drive-api

When I query for MySharedFiles in my app the response is Empty. How to search in Mysharedfiles folder?

```
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Prototyp Client",
        });
        List<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File> result = new List<Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File>();
        List<googleFile> resultString = new List<googleFile>();
        FilesResource.ListRequest request = service.Files.List();
        request.Q = "sharedWithMe and trashed=false";

        try
        {
            Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList files = request.Execute(); } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
            request.PageToken = null;
        }
```

Comment: Show the code you're currently using to make the query

Comment: Hi Wain, you'll find the code in question. thanks

Comment: the query looks fine, can you try to do the same in the API explorer? just to validate the result:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list

Comment: Problem solved. The error was in the code after the request that i don't show in question. In google Api works fine